# Unable to create a database in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, localdb, sql-server-2016-localdb

I installed Visual Studio 2017 with Desktop componennts + SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDb option.

However, when I try to create a database from the Data Connections option from Server Explorer Toolbar, I get this error message:

[image]

What is going on, why after default installation of VS2017 I cannot create a database?

Comment: The server name for LocalDb should be `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDb`.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you. Do you know what is the physical location of newly created database? it didnt ask where to create it.

Comment: I believe it will create it in your profile directory unless you otherwise specify it in the connection string.

Comment: The problem is that it is not asking where to create the db. That is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft changed their versioning scheme:

Older versions used their version number, for example `(LocalDB)\v11.0`, the most recent version changed that and switched to `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDb` as the server name in the connection string section and in the entityFramework section the new value is parameter value="mssqllocaldb" ' .